# Python 3: Replace string in list with limited lines of code

Tags: python, string, list

NOTE: List comprehension, as far as I'm aware, is off the table. Can't use it.

As part of a homework, I am required to, in three lines of code only, take a list of any number of words and strip all of the punctuation within it, keeping it within a list. I tried it like so,

```
for word in splitWords:
    newWord=word.strip(string.punctuation)
    splitWords[word]=newWord
```

which gave an error because it was trying to replace with a string and not an integer. I've scoured the internet for answers and can't find a thing, so I don't know what to do. How would I go about creating this list?

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n91lo0Kmape4UJKOGDQAK5olJO7PjPVr/view?usp=sharing) is the homework for context. It's Problem #4.

Comment: When you say list comprehension is "off the table", do you mean you are not allowed to use it, or you don't know how to use it?

Comment: Technically I'm allowed to use it, but this homework was given with the expectation that I can fit this into three lines of code without using list comprehension, because we haven't learned it yet.

Comment: Right, okay. And so am I correct in saying you'd like a list such as `["hello", "foot-ball", "is", "my", "*favourite*", "sport"]` to become `["hello", "foot ball", "is", "my", "favourite", "sport"]`?

Comment: Before the loop create a new list `new=[]`; then in the loop append the stripped word to the new list.  If you figure out an answer, you can answer your own question. -https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: To PL200, yes, but the list would be several dozens, if not hundreds, long. (Except for foot-ball, where there would be no space. The punctuation is gone with nothing replacing it.)

Comment: To wwii, that's what I was thinking, but that would push me over the line limit. Unfortunately, in order to do that, I would have to make the list in one line, create the for loop in my second line, and then strip and append to the new list all in one line.

Comment: You don't have to assign the stripped word to a name before appending it. You could append the return value of the `str.strip()` method to the new list. ...  [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) would let you keeptrack of the index of each word if you want to stay with that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to StackOverflow!

You should be able to achieve that by using the list index

```
newSplitWords = []
for word in splitWords:
    newSplitWords.append(word.strip(string.punctuation))
```

Comment: `for i in range(len(splitWords)):` - why not just iterate over `splitWords`??

Comment: Thank you, that's what I ended up needing.

Comment: @wwii thank you for the suggestion, I edited the code